# What is the app name in SpreadsheetService

Tags: java, android

I know that this is a simple question and may be a duplicate. But my problem is that I'm new to java android programming (in Eclipse) and i want to get data from Google Spreadsheets. There are some info about declaring SpreadsheetService In [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)  but I can't figure out what is "application name" in SpreadsheetService ("app_name"). I passed empty string like

```
SpreadsheetService servc = new SpreadsheetService ("");
```

and it worked normally in design-time. But it throws an error in android (run-time). I need to know what is "application name" in that bracket. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the class documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService), that String is the name of your application.

> SpreadsheetService(java.lang.String applicationName)
>             Constructs an instance connecting to the Google Spreadsheets service for an application with the name applicationName.

Since you are leaving the String empty, you get an `Exception`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i dont know what the name of the application must be. for example, i have a google accout : edd.zeynal@gmail.com ; i have a spreadsheet named "test1" and there is a worksheet named "sheet1" in it. if i want to get first cell's value what my application name must be ? please show an example

Comment: Just put the name of your Android application where you are trying to connect to SpreadSheetService.

Answer (score 0):

> Constructs an instance connecting to the Google Spreadsheets service for an application with the name applicationName.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService